# CustomTabs not working in React Native

Tags: react-native, android-customtabs

I want to render url using custom tabs. I have installed react-native-custom-tabs using this "npm install react-native-custom-tabs --save" and also made all required changes according to the github tutorial.
changed root build.gradle: -

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"            
        }
                maven {               
                url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle :-

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
import com.android.build.OutputFile
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.animatedapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-cookie')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules     
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1"
}
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

and also made changes into MainApplication.java:-

```
package com.animatedapp;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import im.shimo.react.cookie.CookieManagerPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.github.droibit.android.reactnative.customtabs.CustomTabsPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {  

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new CookieManagerPackage(),
            new CustomTabsPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  } 
}
```

I want to open "https://www.sagepay.com" in my app not on browser. I have made all changes but it give me an error :-
error: package com.github.droibit.android.reactnative.customtabs does not exist

```
import com.github.droibit.android.reactnative.customtabs.CustomTabsPackage;


                                                        ^
/var/www/fif-app/android/app/src/main/java/com/animatedapp/MainApplication.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
            new CustomTabsPackage()
                ^
  symbol: class CustomTabsPackage
2 errors
:app:compileDebugJava FAILED
```

I don't know what can i do ?

Comment: Try linking the project "react-native link" or "rnpm link"after installing npm to link the project. It will use the required import in MainApplication.java

Comment: I have linked the project using " react-native link " . all the package errors are resolved but now its showing error " can't find variable boolean " on front-end. my code 
CustomTabs.openURL('https://www.google.com').then((launched: {boolean}) => {
  console.log('Launched custom tabs: ${launched}')
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
});

Comment: I have also tried this :-
CustomTabs.openURL(url, {
  toolbarColor: '#607D8B',
  enableUrlBarHiding: true,
  showPageTitle: true,
  enableDefaultShare: true
}); but still not succeeded .

Comment: have you seen the example source code [here is the link](https://github.com/droibit/react-native-custom-tabs/blob/develop/example/index.android.js) look into the function **openGoogle()**

Comment: Hi Ranjeet, I am stuck here. I tried react-native link but it's still not working